# Return series from one table for each result in another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having the hardest time searching for a solution to this problem because I can't seem to find the right way to word it.

Say I have one table `tbl_Users` with supervisor names:

```
Employee     | Type
------------ | ----------
Supervisor 1 | Specialist
Supervisor 2 | Analyst
Supervisor 3 | Specialist
Supervisor 4 | Specialist
```

And another table `tbl_Auditable` with employee names:

```
Employee
----------
Employee 1
Employee 2
Employee 3
```

The two are exclusive - the names in `tbl_Users` will not exist in the `tbl_Auditable` table. How can I go about creating a list so that every employee in `tbl_Auditable` is repeated for every row in `tbl_Users`?

```
Specialist   | Employee
------------ | ----------
Supervisor 1 | Employee 1
Supervisor 1 | Employee 2
Supervisor 1 | Employee 3
Supervisor 3 | Employee 1
Supervisor 3 | Employee 2
Supervisor 3 | Employee 3
Supervisor 4 | Employee 1
Supervisor 4 | Employee 2
Supervisor 4 | Employee 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a "cross join".  This can be done like this:

```
select t1.Employee as Specialist, t2.Employee
from tbl_users as t1, tbl_Auditable t2
where t1.type = 'Specialist'
order by t1.Employee, t2.Employee
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution works in MS Access. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use CROSS JOIN

The result is all of the rows in table 1 multiplied by all the rows in table 2.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx

```
SELECT u.Employee AS Supervisor, a.Employee
FROM tbl_Users u
CROSS JOIN tbl_Auditable a
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: Thank you! A cross join was exactly what I needed.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could assist.